# PHP Delete Duplicate Patterns in a String

Tags: php, string, pattern-matching

I got this string:

> Star Wars The Old Republic **The Old Republic**

I marked the obvious in bold: The old republic is a duplicate and I need to get rid of it.

I tried a *preg_replace* like this to detect duplicate patterns following each other like The the... but I fail at getting rid of a longer repetive pattern like The Old Republic.

```
 $str = $game_title;
    $pattern = "/\b([\w'-]+)(\s+\\1)+/i";
    $replacement = "$1";
    print preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str) ."<br>";
```

Comment: This could theoretically be impossible, depending on your desired output. What if you have "The Star Wars The Old Republic The Old Republic." Should the output be "The Star Wars The Old Republic", or "The Star Wars Old Republic", etc, etc.

Comment: All your duplicates will be in html tag?

Comment: It should have been: Star Wars The Old Republic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$str = 'Star Wars The Old Republic The Old Republic';
echo $str = implode(' ',array_unique(explode(' ', $str)));
```

Which will give you **Star Wars The Old Republic** and remove duplicate from string.

Comment: Note that this solution doesn't work for all cases. For example, `The Star Wars The Old Republic The Old Republic` would result in `The Star Wars Old Republic`. That is, it removes all duplicate _words_ except the first one, not "patterns".